# VBA - Stopping a sheet from executing anymore code

Tags: excel, vba

I have an absolute monster of a spreadsheet, with huge amounts of code.

I'd like to "pause" any additional code executions as I finalize and clean up the workbook.

Activating sheets, deactivating sheets, closing the workbook, saving, etc., all trigger macros.

Is there any way to "disable" macros in the workbook until I reopen the workbook?

Comment: Hold `Shift` when opening the excel. It should disable macros. Or open as read~only

Comment: That does it if I'm opening the workbook. But the workbook is already open - I'd like to disable it from this point.

Comment: Just open VBE and mute your macros temporarily once its open (you can just comment them out) and undo before saving. Or you can go to trust center and disable macros.

Comment: The size of the project makes commenting out the macros and commenting them back in prohibitive. That's why I'm looking for a global switch type solution

Comment: I mean, there are 100+ modules in this workbook, so even that would take a good amount of time

Comment: - put your VBE window in Design Mode